# Set scale of object by giving distance between two points in 3D?

Tags: 3d, scale, modeling

Is there any 3D modeling program (Blender, Meshmixer, etc.) that has this function:

1. Select two points
2. Give the program a dimension
3. Program will scale entire model proportionally, so that the distance between those two points is satisfied?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much *all* **3D** **DCC** (**D**igital **C**ontent **C**reation) apps will do this, yes.

[**Blender**](https://www.blender.org/), [**Maya**](https://www.autodesk.com/products/maya/overview), [**modo**](https://www.foundry.com/products/modo), [**3DS**](https://www.autodesk.com/products/3ds-max/overview), [**Cinema4D**](https://www.maxon.net/en/products/cinema-4d/overview/), [**LightWave**](https://www.lightwave3d.com/) - ***all*** of 'em.

Not sure about meshmixer - it's primarily a brute force boolean and retopo tool - it *might* have forced absolute scale tools, but I've not looked for that use in it - I just use [**modo**](https://www.foundry.com/products/modo) for any real modeling work.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hmm... I've been searching far and wide for the function to do this in Blender, but I cannot find any documentation on such function.  Is there a specific name for this operation?

Comment: @TarasPalczynski Most probably its 3 functions. (anything that is many can be combined to one).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not a Blender guru - I can tell you how to do absolute scale of a mesh based on known vertex distances in modo... there it's in the snaps and precision palette - I'd use the button called "reference scale" to input the known value and the whole mesh resizes.

Comment: @TarasPalczynski You should ask in [Blender.SE](https://blender.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @ZachSaucier I already asked in Blender.SE before [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145002/set-scale-of-object-by-giving-distance-between-two-points).  I'm not currently satisfied with the one answer provided there, as it's not necessarily an "exact" solution.

Comment: @TarasPalczynski Then comment saying that there... no need to cross-post